# Use regex in grep while while using two files

Tags: linux, grep

I know that you can use regex in grep and use patterns from a file to search another file. But, can you combine these two options?

For example, from the file where the patterns come from (with the -f option for use patterns from a file), I only want to use the first column to search the second file.

I tried this:

```
grep -E '^(*)\b' -f file_1 file_2 > file_3
```

To grep the first column from file_1 with the * wildcard, but it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: If you still want I can provide an example but the answer I got solved my problem already. Greping from standard input was the solution here. I didn´t know that it was possible ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep doesn't use wildcards for patterns, it uses *regular expressions*, so `(*)` makes little sense.

If you want to extract the first column from a file, use `cut -f1` or `awk '{print $1}'` (or `sed` or `perl` or whatever to extract it), the redirect to `grep` using the special `-` (i.e. standard input) as the source file:

```
cut -f1 file1 | grep -f- file_2 > file_3
```

Comment: Thank you. It works very well. Don't know the - trick for grep :)